# Python: append to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please forgive me if this question is ridiculously simple, I am an absolute newbie.

I am busy looking at a python tutorial, and this one is to generate a Random Walk. It works, but the tutorial isn't very clear on why it works...

It is to simulate a coin toss 10 times, it is either heads or tails (0 or 1). The list then gets updated with each toss, but keeps track of how many times 1 was found

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)

tails = [0]

for x in range(10):
    print(x)
    coin = np.random.randint(0, 2)
    print(coin)
    tails.append(tails[x] + coin)
    print(tails)
```

It is the working of this line that I don't grasp:

```
tails.append(tails[x] + coin)
```

The output I get is:

```
0
0
[0, 0]
1
1
[0, 0, 1]
2
0
[0, 0, 1, 1]
3
0
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
4
0
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
5
0
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
6
0
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
7
1
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
8
1
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
9
0
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
```

For the first iteration x = 0, coin = 0 and the list is then updated to be [0, 0]. In iteration 1 the coin is 1 and then the list is updated to be [0, 0, 1]. Iteration 2 is where I don't understand. Coin is zero, but 1 ends up at the back of the list. This is the expected behavior, as it shows that over the coin tosses up until now, 1 has only been found once, but I do not understand why.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your for-loop starts with with tails already has an entry. The index in the first iteration would be 0 second iteration: 1, third iteration: 2. 

Which means you are generating  the next value of tails with 'tails.append(tails[x] + coin)' while you access the previous element to calculate the latest. 

Your second iteration resulted in: [0, 0, 1] so the next coin flip is zero but now you do the calculation tail[2] (which is 1) + coin (which is 0) which ends up to be 1 

So tails after that execution is [0, 0, 1, 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
tails.append(tails[x] + coin)
```

the crucial part is what happens in the brackets

Since `tails` already has one element (`tails = [0]`), `tails[x]` is essentially "give me the previous result" or also "give me the last result in the list"

Thus `tails[x] + coin` adds the current coin flip to the previous result.
Effectively `tails` is a list describing "how many tails were chosen at this timestep".

`[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]` = "at timestep 8 there was the second coinflip resulting in "tails"